# Verify that socket is being closed

Tags: java, sockets, http, testing

How can I verify that my application is closing a particular HTTP connection?

The close logic is deep inside a complicated library so it's not obvious.

I tried to use the Eclipse debugger and put a breakpoint on `java.io.Closeable` but Eclipse said I can't put a breakpoint on an interface method.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, run `sudo ss -r -p | grep java` at the command line to check if the socket is still open. If `ss` is not installed you can use `netstat` instead. (The Windows equivalent of `grep` is `find`, though I don't know the exact command to use on Windows.)

If you are prepared to grep only by destination server or port, you don't need the `sudo` or the `-p` option in that case.

**Warning:** Note that for HTTP, if the server sends a `Content-Length` header, or a type of response with an [implied content length](http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/chunked/), or uses `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` then HTTP client libraries which support connection keep alive may keep the actual socket open even if you call `close()` on the `InputStream` (an additional clue here is that `curl`/`libcurl` will print a message saying the connection has been kept alive if you use `curl` to make a test request). But if the server doesn't do any of those things, this isn't possible, so the connection should be closed in that case.